# Bulding a pyramid plot with percentage

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, mutate

I'm trying to built a pyramid plot in R. Starting from a dataset with only two variable (Gender and Age), i have been able to modifying it including three variable (Sex, Age group of five years, and Population; the latter referring to the absolute number of people in each age group).
When i try to use the group by and mutate function to add a column with the Population variable express on percentage i receive this error message "unexpected input in:
Error: unexpected input in:

```
db_for_age_plot <- group_by(Sex)%>%
  mutate(Population % = Population/sum(Population)* 100)
```

I paste the code here, hope someone can help.

```
db_for_age_plot$Age <- cut(db_for_age_plot$`Age at onset`, breaks = seq(0, 100, 5), right=FALSE)
    db_for_age_plot$Population <- 1
    db_for_age_plot$Sex <- db_for_age_plot$Gender
    db_for_age_plot<- aggregate(formula = Population ~Sex + Age, data = db_for_age_plot, FUN = sum) 
    db_for_age_plot<- with(db_for_age_plot, db_for_age_plot[order(Sex, Age),])
    db_for_age_plot <- group_by(Sex)%>%
      mutate(Population % = Population/sum(Population)* 100)
```

Comment: You code is missing the dataset to which you want to add the new column, i.e. you probably want `db_for_age_plot <- db_for_age_plot %>% group_by(Sex) %>% mutate(...)`